# How to prevent excel from asking confirmation about a formula?

Tags: apache-poi

I am generating an excel 2010 sheet (.xlsx) containing a formula. This sheet is made available to the user via download from a server.

It works fine, however formula is not initially enabled on the generated excel: user has to click on an "enable content" popup in order to display its results.

Why is that? And is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Are you properly [evaluating the formulas](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) before you save the file?

Comment: Could you post an example of that? I'm not sure to have understood how a switch/case construct can really help me to get rid of that anomaly...

Comment: Did you try looking on the Apache POI website? There are all the examples you could want there....